# Gnome Music Player not showing songs in music folder?

Tags: gnome, music

My Gnome Music Player isn't showing the mp3 files that I have in my `~/Music` folder. I have tried changing the search and indexing with `tracker-preferences` to make sure it searches the Music folder but it still doesn't work.